# EXCEL IF this AND that OR this AND that formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im struggling to get the correct formula for the following logic:

I have used an asterisk as a wildcard.
Where I have used it in the middle of the string it replaces 2 characters, end of the string-2 characters and beginning of the string-6 characters. I am not quite sure how to do this correctly.

```
IF K3="4 x 4" AND L3="FA*FR*" OR 
IF K3="A4" AND L3="FA*FR*" OR
IF L3="*DK"
THEN "0"
ELSE "1"
```

Here is one of the many attempted formulas with no luck.

```
=IF(OR(AND(L3="FA*FR*",K3="4 x 4")), AND(L3="FA*FR*",K3="A4"),(L3="*DK") "0","1")
```

How could I  make this work?

Comment: Wildcards are not valid in your formula. They are being interpreted directly. To use wild cards, use Functions that accept them (eg `SEARCH`, `MATCH`,`COUNTIF` to name a few). See [this reference](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/10/14/excel-wildcard-find-replace-filter-formulas/) for a more complete list.

Comment: I did read about that actually and attempted using COUNTIF with no luck also but will give it another go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF does not allow wildcard, you will need to add SEARCH to it:

```
=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FA*FR*",L3)),K3="4 x 4"), AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FA*FR*",L3)),K3="A4"),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(L3,"*DK"))),0,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Now I am getting no errors, but not the output of "0" when the above conditions are met. Have I used the wildcard correctly? It is replacing many characters, not just one.

Comment: See Edit, I had the criteria reversed.